# How to do testing of Nodejs API's without getting any change in actual DataBase?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am doing testing on Nodejs APIs using mocha and chai. Each time when I do testing, the database populates with some new entries, is there a way to avoid these entries in my database while testing and keep the database unchanged?

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.